# With Apache Pulsar, can I persist messages for some subscribers but not others?

Tags: apache-pulsar

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/next/admin-api-persistent-topics/

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/next/admin-api-non-persistent-topics/

I have a topic for which persistence is important to most subscribers. I want to (temporarily) subscribe to the topic with a client that doesn't care about messages after it disconnects, and so I don't want a ton of messages being wrote to its backlog. As far as I can tell, persistence is only configurable on a topic-level. Is there a way to achieve this subscriber-based persistence?

(in other words, the equivalent functionality to connecting to MQTT with cleanSession=True)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that persistence is at the topic level. Either messages on that topic is persisted to storage disk, or non-persisted to achieve better performance but not durable. Subscription decides how messages can be delivered to consumers. Subscription does not alter how messages are persisted. I think the decoupling is mandatory to separate storage of message vs how message are consumed.

Each message has only one copy in the topic. Subscriptions just maintain various cursors to keep track the message consumption. Subscription does not have duplicates of message but pointers to them. I hope this helps to explain why persistence is a topic level concept not for subscription.